# Missing dependency 'openpyxl' when using pandas in Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read an excel file from S3 using pandas in Lambda. To make pandas work in my Lambda function I've created a custom layer. This custom layer uses a zip file which I've created using the following script:

```
python3 -m pip install wheel
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/d7/ee1b27176addc1236f4a59a9ca105bbdf60424a597ab9b4e13f09e0a816f/pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/be/de078ac5e4ff572b1bdac1808b77cea2013b2c6286282f89b1de3e951273/numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/99/ad6bd37e748257dd70d6f85d916cafe79c0b0f5e2e95b11f7fbc82bf3110/pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/94/a59521de836ef0da54aaf50da6c4da8fb4072fb3053fa71f052fd9399e7a/openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
unzip pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
unzip numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
unzip pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
unzip openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rm pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
rm numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
rm pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rm openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

mkdir python
mv panda* python/
mv numpy* python/
mv pytz* python/
mv openpyxl* python/
zip -r libraries_layer python/
aws s3 cp libraries_layer.zip s3://bucket-with-lambda-libraries/function-name/
```

As you can see, I am installing the packages using wheel and adding them to the zipfile. The contents of the zipfile look like this:

python

- numpy
- numpy-libs
- numpy-1.24.3.dist-info
- openpyxl
- openpyxl-3.1.2.dist-info
- pandas
- pandas.libs
- pandas-2.0.1.dist-info
- pytz
- pytz-2023.3.dist-info

[image: contents zip file]

As far as I can see this seems to be correct. Now when I try to read the excel file using following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import os
from io import BytesIO

def read_from_s3(bucket_name, file_key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    data = file_obj['Body'].read()
    return data


def convert_excel_data_to_df(excel_data):
    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(excel_data), engine='openpyxl')
    return df

def handler(event, context):
    data = read_from_s3(os.environ['INPUT_BUCKET'], event['FILE_KEY'])
    df = convert_excel_data_to_df(data)
    return df
```

I get error:

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.",
  "errorType": "ImportError",
  "requestId": "59838522-be9a-4866-a115-3ddf73618f58",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 36, in handler\n    df = convert_excel_data_to_df(data)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 15, in convert_excel_data_to_df\n    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(excel_data), engine='openpyxl')\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_base.py\", line 478, in read_excel\n    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_base.py\", line 1513, in __init__\n    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py\", line 548, in __init__\n    import_optional_dependency(\"openpyxl\")\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/compat/_optional.py\", line 145, in import_optional_dependency\n    raise ImportError(msg)\n"
  ]
}
```

When reading similar threads concerning this issue, it seems to be a problem with the installment of `openpyxl`. But as far as I can see I've added it correctly. Could this be a version dependency issue? Or is could this be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it resolved, but I will keep the question here so it could help someone else in the future.

It seems that I was missing the dependency `et-xmlfile`, which is a required dependency for `openpyxl`.

I've added the installation of `et-xmlfile` to my installation script as follows:

```
python3 -m pip install wheel
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/d7/ee1b27176addc1236f4a59a9ca105bbdf60424a597ab9b4e13f09e0a816f/pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/be/de078ac5e4ff572b1bdac1808b77cea2013b2c6286282f89b1de3e951273/numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/99/ad6bd37e748257dd70d6f85d916cafe79c0b0f5e2e95b11f7fbc82bf3110/pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/94/a59521de836ef0da54aaf50da6c4da8fb4072fb3053fa71f052fd9399e7a/openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
curl -LO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/c2/3dd434b0108730014f1b96fd286040dc3bcb70066346f7e01ec2ac95865f/et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
unzip pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
unzip numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
unzip pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
unzip openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
unzip et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
rm pandas-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
rm numpy-1.24.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
rm pytz-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rm openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rm et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl

mkdir python
mv panda* python/
mv numpy* python/
mv pytz* python/
mv openpyxl* python/
mv et_xmlfile* python/
zip -r libraries_layer python/
aws s3 cp libraries_layer.zip s3://dev-datalake-python-packages-for-lambda/admail-reception-to-curated/
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.